# Extra RAM memory on disk in VMWare Workstation

Tags: linux, memory, vmware-workstation, vmware-player

Can you add RAM momory to a virtual machine by adding a (say 4 GByte) disc to the system such that this disc is added to the existing memory. What is the procedure for doing this.

Of course you have RAM discs, but this is (kinda) the other way around (i.e. using a disc as memory, instead of using memory as disc),

Comment: Use pagefiles from either within the VM or the host itself. All major OSes support pagefiles/swap and easily increase the possible amount of memory you can hold in RAM if you don't need it.

Comment: Is this TECHIE007 the local sheriff. I see his useless comments all over the forum.

Comment: @whs the only useless comment is your one. The concept here is to minimize the amount of question who ask for the same. So pointing to dups is ok.

Comment: Pointing out the dups is OK. But then you have to provide the links. Else people will not bother looking for them and your comment becomes useless. And what value is there if I know a posting is a dup.